# Django | HTML Render Issue | Querying Issue | Models | Views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, render

In the html file I am trying to render the Remove button. If I just printout out the `{{combo}}` it renders out. But if I try to query it based on the cart model it doesn't render the button. I also tried querying it like this `{% if combo in cart.combo_item.combo.all %}` but it didn't work.

`update-cart.html`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'carts:combo_add_to_cart' %}" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="combo_id" value="{{ combo.id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
    {% if combo in cart.combo_item.all %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Remove?</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
{{combo}}
```

`cart.models`

```
class ComboCartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    combo = models.ForeignKey(Combo, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.combo.combo}"

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    combo_item = models.ManyToManyField(ComboCartItem, blank=True, null=True)
    addon_item = models.ManyToManyField(AddonCartItem, blank=True, null=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    cart_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

`combo.models`

```
class Combo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    combo_regular_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0.00)
    combo_sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0.00)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = ComboManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`views.py`

```
class ComboList(ListView):
    template_name = 'products/list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ComboList, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        combo = Combo.objects.all()
        return combo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the first part of the condition (the `if combo in`...). I would interpret it in the template as "is the value of my variable `{{combo}}` contained in this list?".

From what I understand, you want to check not only that the `combo_list` is not empty, but that at least one item of the list has the `Combo` property assigned. Maybe you could do this traversing the list and using a temporary variable, but Django best practices recommend that you keep all the logic away from the template.

The best option is to define a property in your cart model, and use that from your template. It will also make the template more readable. So you would do:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def is_empty(self):
         return self.combo_item.filter(combo__isnull=False).exists()
```

And then, use this property in your template:

```
{% if not cart.is_empty %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Remove?</button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I have multiple combo items right. If I query it based on True or False. Then it renders the remove button for all the combo items. But I want to render it based on the particular combo that is in the cart

Comment: suppose i have Combo 1, Combo 2, Combo 3. And all those have an option to add to cart. When I click the add to cart button for Combo 2, the remove button should appear only for that Combo i.e Combo 2. Not for Combo 1 and Combo 2

Comment: Oh, but is that a different question? I didn't extract that was your issue in the initial question. For that, I would say again that the best option is to do your logic in the view code, not in templates. So in your `ComboListView`, add that information to your list items (you'll know better what approach suits you the most, if fetching that with a `select_related()` in the `get_queryset()` or in the `get_context_data()` method)

Comment: Thank you! I got your point I will try to do it this way then.